# FFMPEG: Overlay PNG on video with optional audio track

Tags: ruby, audio, video, command-line, ffmpeg

I'm using this command to overlay a transparent PNG over a video, and using the audio track from the video to be the only audio track in the output file. Unfortunately, this fails if the video does not have an audio track. Any recommendations on making this audio track optional (if there isn't one in the video)?

```
ffmpeg -y -i 'video_path' -i 'overlay_path' -filter_complex 'overlay[out],amix=inputs=1,pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c0' -map '[out]' -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ffprobe` to check if the audio track exists and launch a different command with a different mapping when an audio stream is not found.

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams 'video_path'
```